# Google Maps API v3: Filter markers with checkboxes to show intersection of multiple categories

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have defined checkboxes that look like this:

[image]

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Business Development box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Business Development')" /> Business Development </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Capacity Building box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Capacity Building')" />  Capacity Building </label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Communications and Marketing box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Communications and Marketing')" />  Communications and Marketing</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Consulting box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Documentary/Media')" /> Consulting</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Documentary/Media box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Documentary/Media')" /> Documentary/Media</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Economic Development box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Economic Development')" /> Economic Development</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Entrepreneurship box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Entrepreneurship')" /> Entrepreneurship</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Event Planning box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Event Planning')" /> Event Planning</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Financial Management box" onclick="boxclick(this,'skills','Financial Management')" /> Financial Management</label>
```

The checkboxes trigger boxclick, which receives 'category' (skills) and type (e.g. Consulting)

boxclick looks like this:

```
 function boxclick(box,category,type) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category, type);

        } else {
          hide(category, type);
        }
      }
```

`boxclick` triggers `show`, which looks like this

```
 function show(category, type) {
       for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
         if (gmarkers[i][category].toUpperCase().indexOf(type.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
         }
       }
       // == check the checkbox ==
       document.getElementById(type+" box").checked = true;
     }
```

`gmarkers` contains all markers in the map.  `gmarkers[i][category]` will contain all the skills that an individual has, and the indexOf checks to see if the 'type' (e.g. Consulting) is contained within that text array.

I automatically set all the markers to invisible at the beginning (I can't think of another way to conveniently filter things) and after each checkbox all the students who have that skill show up.

*Problem*- If I click on two checkboxes the UNION not the INTERSECTION of all markers appears.  How can I modify the code to make only the INTERSECTION appear? I have very little javascript experience, so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

A temporary running example can be found here: http://dreaminginswahili.com/admin/mapv4.html.  Please feel free to correct me on any other novice mistakes I made.

Also, here's an animated gif of the thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoM51.gif

Cheers!

Comment: Should this read: "How can I modify my code to make only the INTERSECTION appear?" Seems like what you have now is displaying the union...

Comment: Yeah, I thought I said that explicitly in the problem?

Comment: In the problem, you're asking "How can I modify the code to make only the UNION appear".  That seems to be at odds with what you're really asking.

Comment: Oops, you're right!  Thanks!  I re-read it twice, and my brain filled in the right word each time.  You have any ideas on how to implement it?